# How to create a figure of our own

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I want to create the following picture in LaTeX. How can I do this?[image]

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: If you can produce it with a separate tool, just generate a graphics file (PDF, EPS, PNG) and include it in the LaTeX document.

Comment: Or hand draw it and scan it. That's probably the easiest way to get the 'hand-drawn' look of a picture like this.

Comment: by hand drawing and scan it, the quality is very poor. is there any other way to draw something with other softwares such as paint and insert it into latex without using the quality?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a starting point for you. The increased randomness found in your sketch could be added in one of two ways if required:

1. Add more points along each curve using the `to[out=<angle>,in=<angle>]` syntax. For a continuous curve, the difference between `in` for one segment and `out` of the next segment must be 180°.
2. Investigate some path-morphing decorations as discussed in Section 48.2 of the [`pgf` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgf).

Here is the starting point I came up with:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=left}]
  \fill (0,0) coordinate (O) circle (2pt) node[right] {$y$};
  \draw[dashed] (O) circle (1);
  \node[anchor=west] (sbm) at (1.1,0) {smooth blocky\\model};
  \node[anchor=north] (sp) at (0,-1.1) {sparse};
  \node (bm) at (110:1.5) {blocky model};
  \draw (sbm.north west)
    to[out=25,in=190] ($(sbm.north)+(0,0.1)$)
    to[out=10,in=120] (sbm.north east)
    to[out=-60,in=20] ($(sbm.south east)+(-0.5,0)$)
    to[out=200,in=-40] ($(sbm.south west)+(-0.4,0.3)$)
    to[out=140,in=205] (sbm.north west);
  \draw (sp.south east)
    to[out=55,in=-90] (sp.north east)
    to[out=90,in=45,looseness=1.5] (sp.north west)
    to[out=225,in=100] (sp.south west)
    to[out=-80,in=235] (sp.south east);
  \draw (bm.north east)
    to[out=-20,in=180] coordinate[pos=0.2] (bm-start) ++(1.5,-0.5)
    to[out=0,in=180] ++(1.25,0.25) coordinate (Rn)
    to[out=0,in=70] ++(0.5,-2)
    to[out=250,in=15] ++(-2,-1.5)
    to[out=195,in=-30] ++(-3,0.25)
    to[out=150,in=190] coordinate[pos=0.98] (bm-end) (bm.north west)
    to[out=10,in=160] (bm.north east);
  \draw (bm-start)
    to[out=280,in=20] ($(bm.south east)+(-0.05,0)$)
    to[out=200,in=70] ++(-0.2,-0.2)
    to[out=250,in=0] ++(-0.5,-0.2)
    to[out=180,in=275,looseness=1.3] (bm-end);
  \draw[<-] ($(Rn)+(0,-0.35)$) 
    to[out=90,in=180] ++(0.5,0.5) 
    -- ++(0.3,0) node[right] {$\mathbb{R}^n$};
  \draw[<-] (180:1) -- ++(-0.6,0)
    to[out=180,in=50] ++(-1.3,-0.75) node[fill=white] {$y-e$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]